# Ubuntu OpenVPN setup no internet access on client devices

Tags: 14.04, networking, openvpn

I have setup an OpenVPN server using this tutorial on Ubuntu 14.04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

I followed the setup guide to a T, everything went well (or so i thought) and i connected an iPhone with the OpenVPN app, however i have no internet access on the client.

UFW is enabled and configured according to the guide, i dont know where to start looking for the issue as this is my first VPN setup.

Comment: I used that same tutorial.  I had one issue with it because it assumes your internet interface is named `eth0` in the ufw rules section, and mine wasn't.  Perhaps you already checked this, but if not, take a look.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I did wonder about that also. Heres the output from netstat. Looks like its eth0

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
 (cant seem to get the code to format correctly)